# How to extract the content of the first paragraph in html string react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on a react native project and I have an html string json api response.
I am using react-native-render-html to render it, and I can get all paragraphs and apply specific things like number of lines ,etc.. . However I want to get only the first paragraph in the response.

```
str response='<p>text1</p> <p>text2</p> <p>text3</p>';
```

Is it possible to write a regular expression to get only the content of first paragraph which is for example text1 ?

Comment: are you sure there is a space after every <p></p> element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use React Native but in javascript you could do something like that:

```js
const paragraphs = response.split("</p>")
const firstParagraph = paragraphs[0]+'</p>';
```

Or with a regex you can do something like that:

```js
// extract all paragraphe from the string
const matches = [];
response.replace(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g, function () {
    //use arguments[0] if you need to keep <p></p> html tags
    matches.push(arguments[1]);
});

// get first paragraph
const firstParagraph = (matches.length) ?  matches[0] : ""
```

Or like that **(I think it is the best way in your case)**

```js
const response='<p>text1</p> <p>text2</p> <p>text3</p>';
const regex = /<p>(.*?)<\/p>/;
const corresp = regex.exec(response);
const firstParagraph = (corresp) ? corresp[0] : "" // <p>text1</p>
const firstParagraphWithoutHtml = (corresp) ? corresp[1] : "" // text1
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the answer, it works perfect, but suppose i have the first text is empty , how i can get the second or third one.

Comment: WIth the second solution you have an array with all paragraphe tag. You can loop on this array with a .forEach and check if element is empty.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope it will help**

```
var response='<p>text1</p> <p>text2</p> <p>text3</p>';

var firstParagraphElement=response.split("</p>")[0] //firstparagraphElement="<p>text1"

var paragraphContent=firstParagraphElement.replace("<p>","")  //paragraphContent="text1"
```

**javascript `split()` function reference [click](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)**

**javascript `replace()` function reference [click](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

In React Native you can also use [`parse5`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse5) to extract a string from HTML code. I have used this code in a project for doing so:

```
import parse5 from 'parse5'

const isText = (tagName): Boolean => tagName === '#text'

const processNode = (node): String => {
    const nodeName = node.nodeName

    if (isText(nodeName)) {
        return node.value
    }
    if (!node.childNodes) {
        return ''
    }
    return node.childNodes.map((child, index) => processNode(child)).join(' ')
}

export const htmlToText = (html): String => {
    const root = parse5.parseFragment(html)
    return processNode(root).replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()
}
```

Here is a simple JEST test for the function above:

```
test('when full document htmlToText should get text', () => {
    const htmlToText1 = htmlToText("<html><head><title>titleTest</title></head><body><a href='test0'>test01</a><a href='test1'>test02</a><a href='test2'>test03</a></body></html>")
    expect(htmlToText1)
    .toBe(`titleTest test01 test02 test03`);
});
```